# Response from Spring Async controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have wrote spring rest Async controller, that return String JSON response,
When I request the browser complete the response, while  the controller have not completed the processing hence the response is not ready.

I am using Spring Boot, Apache as inbuilt server. 
In EmbeddedServletContainerFactory I have set AsyncTimeout too.

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                connector.setAsyncTimeout(10000000);
            }
        });
```

so How I make the browser wait while the controller Async'ly complete the response?

And the controller is

```
@Async
 @RequestMapping(value = "/id", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDetails(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
       // wrote logic for JSON response....
}
```

Comment: Post your controller...

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added controller in question

Comment: That is not the way to create an async controller. It will spawn a new thread and immediately return. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167020/when-to-use-spring-async-vs-callable-controller-async-controller-servlet-3 for an explanation.  Basically return `Callable<String>` instead of making the method `@Async`.