# How to send response before actions in quarkus/Vert.X

Tags: vert.x, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, vertx-httpclient

Following [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32072255) in **spring**. I want to be able to get in the router the response. and do a response flush, so I could continue work on the server without extending the RTT

meaning, do something like the answer in spring:

```
    public void doSomething(@RequestBody List<Message> messages, HttpServletResponse response) {
    int code = (messages!=null && !messages.isEmpty()) ? HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
            : HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
    if (code != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
        response.sendError(code, res);
        return;
    }
    java.io.PrintWriter wr = response.getWriter();
    response.setStatus(code);
    wr.print(res);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    // Now it it time to do the long processing
    ...
}
```

This is my quarkus code today:

```
@Path("/events")
class EventsRouter {
    val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(EventsRouter::class.java)

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun handleEvent(
        @HeaderParam("User-Agent") userAgent: String?,
        eventPayload: EventPayload,
    ): Response {
        val time = LocalDateTime.now()
        ...
        return Response.ok().build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vert.x [executeBlocking](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code) to run a blocking code asynchronously.

Here's an example (not tested, so please regard this as Pseudo):

```
@Path("/events")
class EventsRouter {
    val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(EventsRouter::class.java);
    private final Vertx vertx;

    @Inject                             
    public EventsRouter(Vertx vertx) { 
        this.vertx = vertx;             
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun handleEvent(
        @HeaderParam("User-Agent") userAgent: String?,
        eventPayload: EventPayload,
    ): Response {
        val time = LocalDateTime.now()
        vertx.executeBlocking(promise -> {
            //Do something...
            promise.complete();
        }, res -> {
            System.out.println("Something was done");
        });
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noam, looks very promising. Unfortunately it will take me time before I'll be able to test it. but I'll grant you the bounty in the hope that it will work :)

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately it's not working... getting out of scope interrupts the code running inside.

Comment: I placed "Thread.sleep(5000)" inside the block and I got sleep interrupt exception. but thanks for the attempt so far.

Comment: @ohadedelstain can you please update your question & add a stack trace?