# @Async in a spring controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Controller REST methods are by default Asynchronized.

Then what is the purpose of @Async annotation?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Async
public Future<Status> getStatus(@PathVariable("id") String id) {    
    return new AsyncResult<Status>(status);    
}
```

Also what is the role of Future interface and AsyncResult class?

Answer (score 3):

**@Async** : Can be used for fire-and-forget scenarios, such as sending an email, kicking off a database job. Caller immediately get the response, while a background job completes processing.

> > what is the role of Future interface and AsyncResult class?

**Future** represents the result of an asynchronous computation.

**AsyncResult** is an implementation for **Future**, wraps the return type of asynchronous execution.

As per [this](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support) blog, Callable is the appropriate return type for controller methods.

ref [Async vs callable controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167020/when-to-use-spring-async-vs-callable-controller-async-controller-servlet-3)

Comment: So @Async will do what Callable and DeferredResult do, which is releasing the container thread and processing the long running task asynchronously in another thread right?

Comment: Yes, that is the behavior of @Async methods.